# Recaptcha v2 module doesn't protect a custom forms

Tags: captcha

Recaptcha v2 as a standard has forms for protection: Comment, Contact Form, User Login (recommended for security), User Login Block (recommended for security), User Register (recommended for security). Customs forms aren't included and they have a protection under the captcha module.
I added a custom form that has protection under the Captcha module, I found my custom form id and added it into the captcha module. My question is how can I add a custom form into "forms for protection" to the Recaptcha module. enter image description here

[image]

Comment: How has the form been built? To me sounds more like a support request to be created on https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/recaptcha. There should be something in the README, but there isn't. Should be clarified somewhere how to use it with custom forms and if this is possible at all.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a bug report or support request to a third-party project hosted on drupal.org or elsewhere and must be reported in its issue queue to track issues in a single place, not here.

Comment: I found on the drupal forum that subject. 

https://www.drupal.org/project/google_recaptcha/issues/2858950#comment-14293600
It looks like they found a way how to do it. The problem is that doesn't work for me. There is even my comment, but after 2 weeks no one replay, so I try here.
I still receive a spam from the only one custom form on the page.

Comment: The form was built as a content type. Space to input name, email etc and button to submit a form.

Comment: You need to add all that to your post here. Which recaptcha module *exactly*? What custom form *exactly*? Please make this a reproducible problem that everybody can relate to without back and forth clarification. Thank you